# Make a command available for two groups in python click?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm using click to write a cli program in Python, and I need to write something like this:

```
import click


@click.group()
def root():
    """root"""
    pass


@root.group()
def cli():
    """test"""
    pass


@root.group()
def cli2():
    """test"""
    pass


@cli.command('test1')
@cli2.command('test1')
def test1():
    """test2"""
    print 1234
    return


root()
```

but this will fail with:

> TypeError: Attempted to convert a callback into a command twice.

How can I share the command between multiple groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`group.command()`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/commands/) decorator is a short cut which performs two functions.  One is to create a command, the other is to attach the command to a group.

So, to share a command with multiple groups, you can decorate the command for one group like:

```
@cli.command('test1')
```

Then, since the command has already been created, you can simply add the click command object to other groups like:

```
cli2.add_command(test1)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click


@click.group()
def root():
    """root"""
    pass


@root.group()
def cli1():
    click.echo('cli1')


@root.group()
def cli2():
    click.echo('cli2')


@cli1.command('test1')
@click.argument('arg1')
def test1(arg1):
    click.echo('test1: %s' % arg1)

cli2.add_command(test1)

root('cli2 test1 an_arg'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
cli2
test1: an_arg
```