# Share a sub-command among multiple top level commands

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a Python project with multiple top level entry points, let's call them `foo` and `bar`. Both entry points use the same code base, and I wish to implement a `foo version` and `bar version` command using the exact same code implementing the `version()` command.

So, in foo.py, I'd say

```
import click

@click.group()
def foo():

@foo.command
@option('--long', ...)
@option('--check', ...)
def version(long, check):
    ...
```

Same in `bar`. How can I avoid duplicating the command definitions in both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514541/7311767), you can build a click command and add it to multiple groups or commands as two separate operations.

#### Build a click command:

First we need to build a click command.  We will use a helper function to decorate the importable command like:

```
import click

def importable_command(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(f):
        return click.decorators.command(*args, **kwargs)(f)
    return decorator


@importable_command('version')
@click.option('--long')
@click.option('--check')
def version_cmd(long, check):
    click.echo('version long: {}'.format(long))
    click.echo('version check: {}'.format(check))
```

#### Add command to group:

Then we can import the command and add it to a group with:

```
from where-ever-we-defined-it import version_cmd

# Add our version command to this group
a_group.add_command(version_cmd)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

def importable_command(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(f):
        return click.decorators.command(*args, **kwargs)(f)
    return decorator


@importable_command('version')
@click.option('--long')
@click.option('--check')
def version_cmd(long, check):
    click.echo('version long: {}'.format(long))
    click.echo('version check: {}'.format(check))


@click.group()
def cli():
    """An Awesome CLI"""


# Add our version command to this group
cli.add_command(version_cmd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'version --long a_long',
        'version --help',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> version --long a_long
version long: a_long
version check: None
-----------
> version --help
Usage: test.py version [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --long TEXT
  --check TEXT
  --help        Show this message and exit.
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  An Awesome CLI

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  version
```

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. Somehow my mind always is bended by the decorator magic.

Comment: I'm having some trouble making it work. I keep getting:

    File "/build/snaprr_infra/common_cli.py", line 40, in <module>
      common.add_command(autoupgrade_cmd)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1221, in add_command
      name = name or cmd.name
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Your sample works fine though, even when I split it... must be some other issue.

Comment: I identified the unrelated issue... Thanks again.